# Mobile Application using .Net

Tags: c#, android, .net

I know there are other questions posted with similar subject line. But I believe, my requirement is very specific. I want to develop a mobile application for Android phones using .Net(C#). I want know, which database I can use and also best free APIs available for developing mobile application(I have heard about Titanium Appcelerator). Kindly Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert in the field, but take a look at Mono Touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use SQLite.Check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439852/Android-with-SQLite-Database-Handling-in-MonoDevel). To understand on SQLite check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android). To start up check [here](http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2011/01/15/Android-applications-in-C-using-Visual-Studio)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I am going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

"With Xamarin.Android, you can harness the full power of C# and .NET. Write shorter, simpler, and more maintainable code using features like LINQ, anonymous types, lambdas, and more."

Check out [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app using C# with [Xamarin MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid), but it is only free until you want to publish your app. I used this with SQLite with no problems (free).

If I may offer some advice based on my experience, be wary with using these packages to create apps. It is far better in my opinion to use native code to utilise the full capabilities of the platform rather than relying on the wrappers created by Xamarin (or any other platform), unless it is a specific requirement of your project.

Good luck!